# Levene test in R

Tags: r

I am Having a little problem doing a Levene test in R. I does not get any output value, only NaN. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Have used the code:

> with(Test,levene.test(Sample1,Sample2,location="median"))

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcLMo.jpg)

Best regards

Comment: Don't post pictures of data. See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it easier to help you. Also explicitly list any packages you are using. `levene.test()` is not a function in base R.

Answer (score 0):

The `levene.test` function assumes the data are in a single vector. The second argument is a grouping variable.

Concatenate your data using the `c()` function: `data=c(Sample1, Sample2)`. Construct a vector of group names like `gp = rep('Gp1','Gp2', each=240)`. Then, call the function as follows: `levene.test(data, gp, location='median')`.

This can also be done directly:

```
levene.test(c(Sample1, Sample2), rep('Gp1', 'Gp2', each=240)), location='median')
```

Comment: probably should be `rep(c('Gp1','Gp2'), each=240)` wouldn't it ? Because `rep('Gp1', 'Gp2', each=240)` returns an error.